# TextFieldShouldReturn not working Xcode 11.2

Tags: swift, xcode, textfield, uitextfielddelegate

I think I've looked at every related question on stack overflow so far and I cannot find out why my code is not working. I'm trying to have the next/return/continue button make the keyboard go away but it doesn't work. Heres my code [Resign Text Field Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5jG6.png)

```
import UIKit

class AddFriendsController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var friendCode: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    //Get rid of keyboard by touching screen
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.view,
                                     action: #selector(UIView.endEditing))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
    //Get rid of keyboard by pressing next
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField == friendCode {
           textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        return true
    }



}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

**Inside ViewDidLoad method write this line of Code**

```
friendCode.delegate = self
```

It will solve your problem.

Comment: I had tried that before and It hadn't made a difference. Just added that line back and ran it again and it still does not work

Comment: I'm using a tab view base for my project. Could that play any part in it? when I press the buttons that bring up new view controllers, the views stack on top of each other and don't dismiss, so maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: Try self.view.endEditing on Tap action Instead of UIVIew.endEditing.

Comment: Sorry this wasn't clear! The  touching screen works perfect, its the second part, dismissing it by pressing the return button which isn't working